# Changing the levels of a pooled DataArray

Tags: julia

I'm looking for a way to modify the levels of a DataArray:

```
result = pool(["a", "a", "b"])
levels(result) = ["A", "B"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick-and-dirty solution, you can change the `pool` field of the object -- it happens to be mutable.

```
result.pool = [ "A", "B" ]

result
# 3-element PooledDataArray{ASCIIString,Uint8,1}:
# "A"
# "A"
# "B"

xdump( result )
# PooledDataArray{ASCIIString,Uint8,1} 
#   refs: Array(Uint8,(3,)) Uint8[0x01,0x01,0x02]
#   pool: Array(ASCIIString,(2,)) ASCIIString["a","b"]
```